# ReactJS: "TypeError: left is undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am using Typescript in my project and whenever the `merge` function is triggered, my web app will show the error "TypeError: left is undefined." `left` and `right` are passed through as arguments. The reason I have them currently set to `any` is because whenever I try to set it to `number[]`, it causes a syntax error to show up on `left.shift()` and `right.shift()`. Any suggestions on how to fix this error so that the function will work properly?

```
const merge = (left: any, right: any) => {
  setArr(arr => {
    while (left.length && right.length) {
      if (left[0] < right[0]) {
        arr.push(left.shift());
      } else {
        arr.push(right.shift());
      }
    }
    
    return [...arr.slice(), ...left.slice(), ...right.slice()];
  });
}
```

EDIT: Here is the full code as well...

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { arrContext } from "../arr-context-provider";
import Visualizer from "../visualizer";

const MergeSort: React.FC = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useContext<[number[], React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[]>>]>(arrContext);
    console.log("Merge Sort");

    useEffect(() => {
      mergeSort(arr);
    }, []);

    const mergeSort = (arr: number[]) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const mid: number = arr.length / 2;

          if (arr.length < 2) {
            return [...arr.slice()];
          }

          const left: number[] = arr.splice(0, mid);
          return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(arr));
        }, 100 * (i + 1));
      }
    }
      
      const merge = (left: any, right: any) => {
        setArr(arr => {
          while (left.length && right.length) {
            if (left[0] < right[0]) {
              arr.push(left.shift());
            } else {
              arr.push(right.shift());
            }
          }
    
          return [...arr.slice(), ...left.slice(), ...right.slice()];
        });
      }

    return <Visualizer />
}

export default MergeSort;
```

Comment: Whatever is calling `merge` is passing `undefined` for `left`.  Changing to `number[]` shouldn't be a syntax error at `left.shift` based on what you've given us. Is the error further up, maybe one whatever is calling `merge`, because it's passing a nullable value to a non-nullable type (`number[]`)

Comment: I believe I'm passing a function through so that may be causing it. Don't know how to fix it though, since I am new to Typescript. Just edited my post so that it also shows all of my code for checking.

Comment: How is your `arrContext` defined? If the default value (or the nearest provider value) is has an undefined `arr` value then you'll be passing that into the `mergeSort(arr)` call in `useEffect`.

Comment: You're calling `merge` inside of `mergeSort` passing the result of another `mergeSort`. That said, `mergeSort` doesn't return anything, so you're calling `merge((() => undefined)(), (() => undefined)());`

Comment: Is there any way to define arrContext from within the component so that it will no longer be counted as undefined?